# How do I implement the onCreateOptionsMenu method in a SherlockFragment?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-optionsmenu

I am really struggling to set up the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method in my Sherlock Fragment, as I usually don't use Sherlock fragments that much. Can someone tell what I have to import and how the implementation works?

Some code that I have:

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, container, false);

        // SOME CODE ...

        return rootView;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The **[onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29)** function of SherlockFragment is exactly like the Fragment one.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu_xyz, menu);
}
```

Also you have to add the following to your `onCreate()` function

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

The imports are:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
```